# keyboard pushes screen down instead of up after upgrading to new xcode and ios 9

Tags: ios, xcode

Getting some odd behavior where the keyboard pushes the screen down instead of up.  This happened after I upgraded to swift 2 and the new xcode 7.  Also, it appeared correctly the first time it ran but now is like this every time.  Any ideas on where or what I should be looking at to debug?

I also get this message in the logs but I thought I saw it before the problems cropped up so not sure it's relevent.

`Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 563160167_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default`

[image]

Comment: Is this the default "scroll to text field visible" when the keyboard appears, or are you doing something with code (that you could perhaps post in your question)?

Comment: just the default stuff that comes with an input field- nothing custom on the keyboard .  screenshot of the settings in the textfield https://www.dropbox.com/s/sgjv5420o73bvyk/Screenshot%202015-09-15%2021.55.50.png?dl=0

Comment: You mention it worked only the first time. What happens if you clean/clean build folder, remove app from device/simulator and build again?

Comment: cleaned, and removed and re-installed and same problem